# In BYFN for Hyperledger - Fabric which files we need to update the name of Org if we want to run byfn just by renaming its org1 name

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am new to Blockchain and trying to learn with Hyperledger.

In BYFN for Hyperledger-Fabric in which files we need to update the name of Org, if I want to run byfn just by renaming its org1 name.

I already tried by renaming in the below files but still I am getting error.

./byfn.sh generate

the above is running fine but while bringing the byfn up it is showing below errors.

Answer (score 0):

In BYFN you need to update configtx.yaml then crypt-config.yaml, this will be used to generate crypto material i.e ./byfn generate after this you need to update docker-compose-cli.yaml. check if there's any dependence in byfn.sh script make the changes then goto script directory you will find multiple scripts make changes there as required. and run ./byfn.sh up

Comment: Thanks Mohammad for quick response. I tried the same, changed in scripts.sh file also still getting the same error as given below

Comment: 2019-09-25 11:51:39.856 UTC [main] InitCmd -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto, folder "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" does not exist
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========

ERROR !!!! Test failed

Comment: @MdAbidKhan first try to bring down network ./byfn.sh down the bring it up